# How can I display items from a dictionary in a html webpage from a Django ListView template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, listview

I'm trying to display the results of a query in a MongoDB database but I can't display the results passed by `views.py`.

Here is the page where I show them by iterating with a for loop over `products`:

```
{% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped" align='center'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">Brand</th>
      <th align="center">Perfume Name</th>
      <th align="center">Gender</th>
      <th align="center">Theme</th>
      <th align="center">Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for element in products %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ element.q0.Results.0.Brand.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.q0.Results.0.Name }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is views.py where I request and send them.

```
import pymongo
import todo.config as config
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.db.models import Q


username = config.username
password = config.password

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/ifresearch?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = client.test.sephora_backup3

...

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(query)
        products = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": query, "$options": "i"}}))
        print("products: ", products)
        return products
```

There are results in the products but nothing is shown in the html

Comment: what does that `print("products: ", products)` output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView sets a variable named `object_list` in your context with the results of `get_queryset`. Also if you set `context_object_name` it uses that name and if not it tries to use the model name if the object_list has it (meaning it is a queryset).

In your case you loop over `products` but there is no such context variable. You should set `context_object_name = 'products'`:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    
    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(query)
        products = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": query, "$options": "i"}}))
        print("products: ", products)
        return products
```